# Add and compare items of struct in Solidity (dealing with struct in Solidity)

Tags: solidity, remix, contract-design, mapping, struct

How can I know the whole `entityData` of the struct and add a new entity only if it didn't exist before (ensure no replicated data)?

```
struct EntityStruct {
   uint entityData; 
   bool isEntity; 
   bool iscontent; 
   uint vote; 
   uint predata; 
}

mapping(address => EntityStruct) public entityStructs; address[] public entityList;

function newEntity(address entityAddress, uint entityDataa) public payable returns() {

entityStructs[entityAddress].entityData = entityDataa; 
entityStructs[entityAddress].isEntity = true; 
entityList.push(entityAddress) - 1;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do it is to hash the contents of the `struct` and use that for the uniqueness check. Then you have a choice. It is conceivable that the hash is the index to the structs but that may be unworkable if the data is subject to change and belongs to an `address`. In that case, it's a separate mapping.

```
mapping(bytes32 => bool) public exists;
```

Consider:

```
function generateHash(
   uint entityData,
   bool isEntity, 
   bool iscontent, 
   uint vote,
   uint predata
)
   public 
   pure
   returns(bytes32 hash)
{
   return keccak256(abi.encodePacked(entityData, isEntity, iscontent, vote, predata);
}
```

It's up to you to maintain the structure and enforce the rules, so your insert function could do something like:

```
bytes32 index = generateHash( args ...);
require(!exists[index], "Duplicate");
exists[index] = true;

// carry on
```

You could roll that up into modifiers or simple functions if it's repetitive:

Hope it helps.